# Excel count between two array constants - only returning first three instances

Tags: arrays, excel

I am trying to count only completed components in a manufacturing shift report.

Example:
I have 6 components (each having three parts) in column A represented by array constant {1,2,3,4,5,6} (in other words this column repeats three times per component - 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6)

I have three parts per component in column B represented by array constant {"a","b","c"}. (in other words component 1 has an "a" part on one line, a "b" part on the next line and a "c" part on the third line in the shift print report.

I also have a status/ critera comment in column C represented by "Complete"

My formula trying to count only completed components (each having it's three parts) is:
{=sum(countifs(A:A,{1,2,3,4,5,6},B:B,{"a","b","b"},C:C,"Complete"))}

THIS HOWEVER ONLY WORKS FOR THE FIRST THREE COMPONENTS, i.e. NOT 4,5,6.

Please help with this as my full application would be up to a hundred components each shift each with three parts that I must report as ready for despatch only when column C is "Complete".

I am doing this manually at this time which is massively numbing work.

An alternative formula I tried but which only works if A:A has one value:
 {=sum(if((A:A={1,2,3,4,5,6})*(B:B={"a","b","c"}),1,0))}

I am totally confounded by this one - awesomely braintwisted!

I tried looking for resources on mismatched array constants, which I thought relevant in this case but do not understand how to proceed (anyway).

Please can some one show me the light!

Thanks,
Stu

Answer (score 2):

Try transposing one (but not both) of your array constants so that it is orthogonal to the other, i.e. **either**:

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,{1,2,3,4,5,6},B:B,{"a";"b";"c"},C:C,"Complete"))`

**or**:

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,{1;2;3;4;5;6},B:B,{"a","b","c"},C:C,"Complete"))`

Note that these constructions do **not** require committing as array formulas, i.e. with CSE.

If you're interested in an explanation as to this required syntax, see here:

http://excelxor.com/2014/09/28/countifs-multiple-or-criteria-for-one-or-two-criteria_ranges/

Regards

Comment: Thanks for you feedback - I am checking the reference now.

Comment: i think he meant  orthogonal  :)

Comment: Hi XOR LX, both formulas in your answer are the same? I still get three as the value, this is a tough one!

Comment: @Stuart Does your version of Excel use the comma or semi-colon as argument separator within functions?

Comment: "array"? No that's a new one for me too

Comment: Hi XOR LX, i read your article and tried the comma versus semi colon, very useful in that the x:y dimension (semicolon in one argument while retaining comma in other argument) gives new dimension (pun) to the results. Thanks. However I am struggling to achieve a formula where components are only counted after all parts are completed. Hope you can help. Thanks, Stu

Comment: Not sure what you mean - sorry. Perhaps you can post a very small mock example table with your expected results?

Comment: sorry i cannot add pics yet - too noob to stack overflow. But my column A is three lines of 1, then three lines of 2, etc until 6 which ends in row 18. My second column is a,b,c repeated for each number in column A. The column C value is "x" for this argument and represents completed assy's. "x" is intermittant as per shift completion. I want to calc how many full assy's have an "x" at the end of each shift? Can I email you some where else with the tables?

Comment: @XOR XL, Hi, I joined your mailing list, heading off now, if you get a chance send me your email address and we can chat further. Thank you.